# Is every fiber of a morphism between varieties of pure dimension?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Suppose $f\colon X\to Y$ a morphism of varieties with connected fibers, is it true that all the fibers have pure dimension?

Comment: I'm not sure why this was downvoted or voted to close. With questions of this difficulty, it can't always be expected that the OP has an idea of how to even approach the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not true. Take the blow-up of the affine space $\mathbb{A}^n$ at the origin (see [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blowing_up)). Fibers over any point except the origin are just single points, so $0$-dimensional, and the fiber over the point $0$ is $\mathbb{P}^{n-1}$.

Comment: In my example it is still the case: generic fiber has pure dimension 0, and the exceptional fiber has pure dimension $n-1$

Comment: Yes you are right, we can still get counter example of morphism between smooth varieties with fiber not of pure dim by blowing up.

Answer (score 1):

No, let $X \to Y$ be a finite map of surfaces of degree $2$ and let $y\in Y$ have distinct preimages $x_1, x_2$. Let $\tilde X$ be the blowup of $X$ at $x_1$. Then $\tilde X \to Y$ has fiber $E \sqcup \{x_2\}$ over $y$, where $E \cong \mathbb{P}^1$ is the exceptional divisor.

Comment: Thanks..really sorry I forgot a condition..the fibers are connected..?